# Groovy Oracle XMLTYPE

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy, xmltype

I have a procedure in Oracle that looks like this.

```
        PROCEDURE p_main_xml (p_term       IN     VARCHAR2
                         , p_crn        IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                         , p_pin        IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                         , p_hash       IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                         , p_updated    IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
                         , p_xml_clob      OUT xmltype)
```

I am trying to call this from a grails app and get the XML. The result it 8meg or so.

My call looks like this.

```
            sql.call '{call cl_sectiondownload_pk.p_main_xml(?,?,?,?,?,?)}', [termCode, crn, pin, hash, updated, java.sql.Types.SQLXML], { p_xml_clob ->
                //println "this is my sql: " + p_json
                xmlOut = p_xml_clob
            }
```

I am getting this error from Oracle.

wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P_MAIN_XML'

Details:

- Grails Version: 4.0.10
- JVM Version: 11.0.2
- Oracle 12.1.0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

XML in oracle is quite specific object

unfortunately don't have oracle right now but something like this should work

```
sql.call('''
    DECLARE
        x XMLTYPE;
    BEGIN
        cl_sectiondownload_pk.p_main_xml(?,?,?,?,?,x);
        ?:=x.getCLOBVal();
    END;
''', [.., sql.VARCHAR]){x-> ... }
```

maybe instead of `sql.VARCHAR` use `sql.CLOB`

assume that `sql` is an instance of  `groovy.sql.Sql`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Never thought to throw in an anonymous block.

My next issue is to increase the performance of the CLOB download.

Comment: now my next issue is speed. the downloading of the clob and converting it to string takes way longer than it should.

Comment: you could try to: 1/ use native oracle classes to work with xml (you need more then ojdbc jar for this) 2/ make your stored procedure to return chunks of xml instead of one large object. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb11jav.htm